# Image doesn't flip with css

Tags: html, css

When I apply the class **prev** it doesn't flip the image.

I'm kinda stuck on why it does not work, I tried it with Chrome, Firefox and IE and none of them work.

```css
.pbtn {
  background-image: url('../../images/linkpil.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-position: center center;
  &.first {
    display: none;
  }
  &.next {
    background-color: #C9E2E5;
  }
  .prev {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
  }
  a {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px; //hide text
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pbtn">
  <a href="http://sp16/sites/danbolig/Pages/Default.aspx?cache=clear&amp;driftPage=1" class="driftPageprev prev"></a>
  <a href="http://sp16/sites/danbolig/Pages/Default.aspx?cache=clear&amp;driftPage=1" class="driftPagenext next"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not CSS, it's SCSS.

Comment: Please post this to a jsFiddle which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Dai Or LESS, but there is a CSS library here :)

Comment: Yes sorry, its LESS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your less code, it looks like your html has to be this.

```
<div class="pbtn next">
  <a href="http://sp16/sites/danbolig/Pages/Default.aspx?cache=clear&amp;driftPage=1" class="driftPagenext"></a>
</div>
<div class="pbtn prev">
  <a href="http://sp16/sites/danbolig/Pages/Default.aspx?cache=clear&amp;driftPage=1" class="driftPageprev"></a>
</div>
```

and replace

```
&.next {
background-color: #C9E2E5;
}
.prev {
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
-o-transform: scaleX(-1);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
transform: scaleX(-1);
filter: FlipH;
-ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

With:

```
&.next {
background-color: #C9E2E5;
}
&.prev {
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
-o-transform: scaleX(-1);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
transform: scaleX(-1);
filter: FlipH;
-ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css will do nothing because there is nothing in `a` to transform.

The background image is on the parent, and there is no content or image in the `a`. For all we know the transform is working fine but we can't see anything.